# SQL Server and NodeJS [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database in `node.js` and I am using the `mssql` and `msnodesqlv8` modules but I am getting an error. I have code that works fine on my local machine and the error I get it on the live server. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Below is my code

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8')

const config = {
    user: 'user\\name',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'server',
    database: 'database',
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
};

sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) throw(err);
    console.log('connected')
});
```

The error I get:

```
ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
    at D:\services\nodejs\BIDVESTFM_Rental_Inspection_Upload_Processor\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:56:17
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (D:\services\nodejs\BIDVESTFM_Rental_Inspection_Upload_Processor\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\connection.js:145:15)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:471:21) {
  code: undefined,
  originalError: [Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified] {
    sqlstate: 'IM002',
    code: 0,
    severity: 0,
    serverName: '',
    procName: '',
    lineNumber: 0
  }
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Aside... choose one authentication method, SQL Logins or Windows Authentication. When you specify `user` and `password` properties you're using SQL Login authentication and it requires that an SQL Login exists on the target instance with those username and password details. When you specify `trustedConnection: true` you're using Windows Authentication and the target instance must have the appropriate Windows account (or group containing the account) configured - and the NodeJS process must be running under those credentials.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a value for `options.driver: "..."` to satiate the _and no default driver specified_ part of the error message?

Comment: Have you figured it? I have the same error, it works fine on local machine but when i deploy on live server it give the same error

Comment: In my case, I use iisnode on windows server, install ODBC Driver, SQL Native Client and change Application Pool default property `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to `false` solved the problem

Comment: I am also stuck here, any solutions? Post your answers pls if you got one